# How to reverse usermod -s /bin/false?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, ftp

I only want to disable SSH access but retain FTP access to user `myuser`.
I've perform the following command `usermod -s /bin/false myuser`.
Upon testing, it disable both SSH and FTP.

1. How can I reverse this?
2. How can I disable SSH access for `myuser` but allow FTP access?

Comment: What OS and distribution are you using?  What SSH and FTP server software?

Comment: @depquid Debian Squeeze, Pro FTP, how do I find out what type of SSH?

Comment: To get the ssh version run `ssh -V`. To reverse what you did do `usermod -s /bin/bash`.

Comment: @terdon Thanks `OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010`

Comment: For $ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
This worked well:
$sudo usermod -s /bin/bash myuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow FTP access, try turning off ProFTPD's check for a valid shell by setting the following in `/etc/proftpd.conf`:

```
RequireValidShell Off
```

Source: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/faq_full.html#AEN267

**WARNING:** If you have other users on the system whose FTP access has been disabled by setting their shell to one that is not a valid login shell, making this directive change will give them FTP access.